# How to escape f:selectItem itemLabel attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How to escape `f:SelectItem itemLabel` attribute so that I can add a hyperlink in the label?

Using following code, I was able to escape `h:outputText` but not `f:selectItem`.

```
            <h:outputText value="MyLink &lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; &gt;Google &lt;/a&gt;" escape="false"/>              
            <h:selectOneRadio id="p" value="#{bean.somevalue}" required="true" >
                <f:selectItem escape="false" escapeItem="false" itemLabel="One &lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; &gt;Google &lt;/a&gt;" itemValue="O" />
                <f:selectItem escape="false" escapeItem="false" itemLabel="Two &lt;a href=&quot;http://stackoverflow.com&quot; &gt;Stackoverflow&lt;/a&gt;" itemValue="T" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
```

I want something as in following image

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a documentary bug in JSF. The [actual attribute](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.13/javax/faces/component/UISelectItem.java#UISelectItem.setItemEscaped%28boolean%29) is named `itemEscaped`, not `escapeItem` ([as incorrectly documented in VDL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItem.html)) or `escape` (which Eclipse autocomplete indeed autosuggests for some unknown reason, but is actually totally absent in VDL).

The following construct should work for you (at least, it does for me on Mojarra 2.1.17):

```
<h:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem itemEscaped="false" itemLabel="One &lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot; &gt;Google &lt;/a&gt;" itemValue="O" />
    <f:selectItem itemEscaped="false" itemLabel="Two &lt;a href=&quot;http://stackoverflow.com&quot; &gt;Stackoverflow&lt;/a&gt;" itemValue="T" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: I just fixed the documentation error.  Better late than never: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1107?focusedWorklogId=24233&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel#worklog-24233

Comment: For me it is not escaped but it is not shown as a link.