# <p:selectOneButton> with images

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, html-escape, selectonebutton

I'm using JSF with Primefaces, I want to use a buttonset of radiobutton with only images but I can't make it work.

Here's the code:

```xml
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{LoginBean.user}" >  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;img src=&quot;/myApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/myImg1.png?ln=img&quot;/&gt;" itemValue="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;img src=&quot;/myApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/myImg2.png?ln=img&quot;/&gt;" itemValue="2"/>
    </p:selectOneButton>
```

I tried escaping characters with "escape", "escapeItem" and even "itemEscaped" attributes.
I read about the last one [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238646/how-to-escape-fselectitem-itemlabel-attribute). The solution in that question uses `<h:selectOneRadio>`, not `<p:selectOneButton>`.

**Note:** I know it works using jQueryUI `buttonset()` method (Primefaces uses it on the background) so it's not a script problem..

So, is it posible to do this with `<p:selectOneButton>`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea... what about nesting the image inside the `<selectItem>` tag? Like `<selectItem itemValue=".."><img src="..."></selectItem>`

Comment: @SJuan76 the images render outside of the buttons group, or whatever container you use, and the buttons are all empty because theres no text to fill them (they are `<spans>` in the source code) :(

Comment: @SJuan76: that won't work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the renderer of `<p:selectOneButton>` doesn't take into account any HTML in labels. Your best bet is to set it as CSS background image instead.

Given a

```
<p:selectOneButton ... styleClass="buttons">
```

you can style the individual buttons using CSS3 `:nth-child()` pseudoselector

```css
.buttons .ui-button:nth-child(1) {
    background: url("#{resource['img/myImg1.png']}") no-repeat;
}
.buttons .ui-button:nth-child(2) {
    background: url("#{resource['img/myImg2.png']}") no-repeat;
}
```

If you're however targeting browsers which don't support it ([certain IE versions](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)), then you can't go around performing the job via JS/jQuery.

```
$(".buttons .ui-button:eq(0)").css("background", "url('resources/img/myImg1.png') no-repeat");
$(".buttons .ui-button:eq(1)").css("background", "url('resources/img/myImg2.png') no-repeat");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you're using resource `library` is not entirely right. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) to learn more about it.

Comment: I read the post you made a week ago while searching for this and it's great, thanks. I use the library that way in the code just to try to make it work. Regarding the CSS workaround, overriding the background image makes the buttons.. well.. not looking like buttons anymore xD just clickable images. I should stick with jQuery UI buttonset.. maybe?

Comment: Huh? Isn't that exactly what you want? If you don't want clickable images, what exactly do you want then?

Comment: I want radiobuttons (functionality) with button style (rouded corners, highlight on mousehover, etc) but with images as content instead of text. Overriding CSS I step over the look and feel of `ui-button` and i get flat images :/

Comment: I see what you're getting at. Well, I don't think that there's another way than manipulating the HTML DOM using jQuery by inserting the desired `<img>` element in place of button text.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to use Font Awesome Icons. That is possible by setting `font-family: FontAwesome` and using this codes: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{mybean.alignment}" style="font-family: FontAwesome;">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="align-left" itemLabel="&#xf036;"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="align-center" itemLabel="&#xf037;"/>
   <f:selectItem itemValue="align-right" itemLabel="&#xf038;"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```