# JSF SelectItems and escaping (xss)

Tags: jsf, xss, mojarra

there is a selectOneMenu in my example with a f:selectItems-attribute. The select-items are resolved from my bean like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" var="obj" itemValue="#{obj}" itemLabel="#{obj.name}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The method getSelectItems() in my bean looks like that:

```
    public List<MyObject> getSelectItems() {
        List<MyObject> list = new LinkedList<MyObject>();

        MyObject obj = new MyObject("Peter");
        list.add(obj);

        return list;
    }
```

The objects that are displayed are simple objects with a attribute "name".

Nothing special up to this point. But now i change my method to that:

```
 public List<MyObject> getSelectItems() {
        List<MyObject> list = new LinkedList<MyObject>();

        MyObject obj = new MyObject("<script>alert('xss is bad');</script>");
        list.add(obj);

        return list;
    }
```

The javascript doesn´t get escaped by MenuRenderer-Class and my page shows me the alert-message.

Is there any cause why the default value of the escape-attribute of SelectItem is "false"?
How can i fix that problem? (I use Mojarra 2.1.7)

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238646/how-to-escape-fselectitem-itemlabel-attribute)

Comment: @VikasV: OP's concrete problem concerns the other way round.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default should indeed not have been `false`. I've reported it as [issue 2747](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2747).

In the meanwhile, add `itemLabelEscaped="true"` to escape it anyway.

```
<f:selectItems ... itemLabelEscaped="true" />
```

Note that this is only necessary when you're using `GenericObjectSelectItems`, i.e. when you're supplying a `E[]`/`List<E>`/`Map<K, V>` instead of `List<SelectItem>`/`SelectItem[]`. Also note that escaping is only absolutely mandatory when it concerns user-controlled input (which is fortunately very rarely the case in dropdown values).

Comment: This has been fixed in JSF 2.2 ([JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1167](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1167)) and Mojarra 2.2.6 ([JAVASERVERFACES-3143](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3143)).