# How do I get the HTML "label" attribute into an f:selectItems?

Tags: html, jsf-2, jquery-select2, html-select

The [JSF-2 tag f:selectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) that iterates over a collection of POJOs offers the parameters `value` and `itemLabel`

These generate `<option>` elements of the form

```
<option value="value">itemLabel</option>
```

Now, [HTML offers another attribute](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_option_tag.cfm) called `label` for the `<option>` tag

```
<option value="value" label="something_else">itemLabel</option>
```

but I can't see any way how to make use of that one through JSF. The background for the question is that I have my itemLabels in a localized language, but want Select2 (which replaces the `<select>` here) to be able to autocomplete and match the English name, too. This I want to hide in the `label` attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by what I consider a rather dirty trick:

I generated the options using `f:selectItems` as follows:

```
    <h:selectManyMenu class="MySelectField" id="MySelectField" name="input"
        value="#{...}" converter="...">
            <f:selectItems value="#{...}" var="..."
                itemLabel="Localized_Label|EnglishLabel/NorwegianLabel"
                />
    </h:selectManyMenu>
```

producing

```
<option value="SOME_CODE">Localized_Label|EnglishLabel/NorwegianLabel</option>
```

I then jQueried the part I want to hide into the `label` attribute (and configured Select2 to also match user input against said attribute):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".MySelectField option").each(function(){
            tmp=$(this).text().split("|");
            $(this).attr('label',tmp[1]);
            $(this).text(tmp[0]);
            });
        $(".MySelectField").select2({
            matcher: function(term, text, opt) {                    
                return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0
                || opt.attr("label").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
            }
        });
    });
```

resulting in

```
<option value="SOME_CODE" label="EnglishLabel/NorwegianLabel">Localized_Label</option>
```

with a Select2 called on top of that.

This now allows the user to get Select2's autocompletion both for English and Norwegian input, irrespective of the chosen localization.

Comment: One alternative similar to what is discussed by BalusC in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238646/how-to-escape-fselectitem-itemlabel-attribute) would be to use ``itemEscaped="false"`` and inject the English labels as comments like so: ``<option...>Localized_Label<!--EnglishLabel/NorwegianLabel--></option>``, but that appears to work only for ``SelectOneRadio`` and not for ``SelectOneMenu`` or ``SelectManyMenu``, where all tags are cleaned away automatically.