# In NetBeans, Mojarra 2.2 outputStyleSheet doesn't have media attribute

Tags: jsf, netbeans, outputstylesheet

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 and Mojarra 2.2 where according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) there's a `media` attribute and this is not the case, I get the following message:

> The attribute media is not defined in the component outputStyleSheet

So the problem I know is with NetBeans 8.0.2. When I launch the application, It runs properly so does anyone know why NetBeans shows this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documentary bug in the tag library declaration file of the Mojarra implementation. The Mojarra guys forgot to declare the `media` attribute of `outputStylesheet` tag in the [`html_basic.taglib.xml` file](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/jsf-ri/conf/share/html_basic.taglib.xml#L6575). Netbeans is relying its tag/attribute validation on it and therefore gives false warnings.

The tag library declaration entry of the attribute is not necessary for the technical functioning of the attribute (not in components, tagfiles, nor composites) and that's why it just works fine.

The same documentary bug problem is known with below tag attributes:

- [`<ui:fragment rendered>` - fixed in Mojarra 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/)
- [`<f:selectItem itemEscaped>` - fixed in Mojarra 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238646/how-to-escape-fselectitem-itemlabel-attribute/)

If you [report](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES) the `<h:outputStylesheet media>` documentary bug, it'll likely be fixed in Mojarra 2.3.

Comment: thank you!. How do I report properly ?  I suppose  here: http://corejsf.com/bugs2.html   but I want to make sure I fill the correct information.

Comment: The word "report" in my answer is clickable.

Comment: BTW, I was looking around and from the **issues** link :  https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel         I clicked on the `bug` link at the bottom right of the page, and When clicking on  `Reported by me` the page goes into an infinite loop and shows  `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: New to JIRA tool? Just signup/login and you'll see "create issue" button in top bar. Anonymous reporting is not permitted. That redirect loop is just a misconfiguration on their side.